# Data according to login session by using ajax datatables Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I display data to the datatable according to the data the user is logged in to? 
The data that will appear in the datatables is the only data from the user who is logged in.

**My_model.php**:

```php
private function _get_datatables_query()
{       
    $this->db->from($this->table);

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
    {
        if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
        {               
            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}

public function get_data()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right off the top of my head, if users do not correspond to some database field that you might use as a criteria (e.g. users location, age, etc), you may introduce one:

- Append some sort of 'access level' column to your database user profile table;
- Prepare some database view, that contains source table rows along with certain access level, using desired criteria;
- Based on logged in user, do SQL (using user id as a parameter) that queries only those entries that have access level less or equal to that granted to the user.